# Who is this mysterious adventurer?

Tags: riddle

I like to shower and I sail the seas,

I sunbathe and I blow things up,

I feed babies and I chew into things.

Who am I?

HINT:

> I am close to your head.

HINT 2:

> You will find me in the market

HINT 3:

> I know my limits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it -

> A CAP

I like to shower and I sail the seas,

> Shower Cap, Cap - short for captain?

I sunbathe and I blow things up,

> People wear caps to keep the sun from their eyes, Blasting cap

I feed babies and I chew into things.

> Bottle Cap, Capped teeth

HINT:1

> am close to your head. -Like a cap

HINT 2:

> You will find me in the market -Where you might buy a cap?

HINT 3:

> I know my limits -A limit is sometimes called a cap

+1  Love these riddles.

Comment: Thumbs up! You got it

Answer (score 2):

> Air (in the general, vague use of the term)

Explanation:

> You can say air 'showers' when it rains. The air sails the seas in the form of wind.
>  The air sunbathes I guess, as it sits there not moving much on beaches. Air can 'blow up' balloons.
>  Everyone needs to breathe, including babies, so air feeds them oxygen. Air 'chews' into things when they decay/corrode.